# DIV Wrap two different elements inside a DIV by JS

Tags: jquery

Imagine this

```
<div id="container">
     <label>Enter the code</label>
     <input maxlength="5" size="5" class="input_code" title="" type="text" value="" name="code_holder">
     <img src="image.jpg">
     <div class="small-message">Sample Text</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <div id="error-message"></div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap only the image and the `div.small-message` with a div class or id let's say

```
#wrap-inside/.wrap-inside
```

Tried searching and trial and error for an hr now but no luck.. I know this is possible, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wrapAll()`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        $('img, .small-message', '#container').wrapAll('<div id="wrap-inside" />');
    });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTb7r/)

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the help.. i tried both of your methods but i can't get it to work..

view-source:http://privatebook.com.au/contact-pb line:23

Already tried using jQuery instead of the $ sign, but still no luck.. any idea why?

Does the script should be inside the <head>?

Thanks again

Comment: @RonJb - I edited the code, replace everything, **do not** keep the window load crap, and place the code in the HEAD section, and remember to include jQuery.

Comment: Thanks!! i just added the src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" and changed the code and it worked.. now i can still keep the site fully responsive,, I'll have to do this tomorrow,,

Thank you soo much Adeneo!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$('#container').find('img, div.small-message').wrapAll('<div id="wrap-inside"></div>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6gbDX/)

[Another variation](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6gbDX/2/)